# Could I write app.get in express to dynamically fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Instead of writing one of these for every file I want to serve could I write something to the effect of...

```
app.get('/' + x, function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(x + '.html');
});
```

If so, how would I actually do it? Can I parse x from the req before doing app.get or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using static files, definitely use the static folder. if you need to use sendfile try this:

```
app.get('/:pagename'  , function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(req.params.pagename + '.html');
});
```

Comment: this is exactly the functionality I was looking for even tho i didn't give the best example, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Place all your HTML files that you want to have public in a folder name `public`

Then add [`express.static`](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-static.html) to your middleware list

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));`

To your configuration. Now these files will be routed statically. So if you have a file at location `/public/foo/bar.html` then `/foo/bar.html` will load and return that file.

Comment: What if I want to do something like... `res.sendfile('layout.html');` but `doSomething(x)` afterwards?

Comment: also, in the html example I'd want `/foo/bar` to get bar.html, not `/foo/bar.html`

Comment: Express uses connect's staticProvider for this feature.  You can find the source code to staticProvider in express's node_modules/connect/lib/connect/middleware/staticProvider.js  If you need something drastically different from what it provides, the source code makes an excellent starting point.

Comment: @fancy then use views and middleware